# How to make triangle div above a rectangle div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a Triangle on top of a rectangle div. The triangle needs to be the width of the page and also be responsive. The upper right and left parts of the div (where no triangle exists) needs to be transparent.

I have an image of what it should look like but it's very difficult to see due to the similar dark colors. The upper right and left of the rectangle div needs to be transparent.

Does anyone know how I can recreate the highlighted rectangle in the image below?

I've been trying for hours by searching through stackoverflow and haven't been able to figure it out from other questions.

Thank you!

[image: Image of what it should look like]

Comment: This ? https://jsbin.com/donuzaloqe/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that :

```
<html>
<body>

<style>

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.rectangle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #777;
}

.triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50vw solid transparent;
    border-right: 50vw solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid black;
}

</style>

<div class='rectangle'>
    <div class='triangle-up'></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

(I changed the colors to make it easier to see)

Comment: This is awesome, thanks. The only issue is for some reason it is wonky. The right side is higher than the left and I'm not sure why that is. Here is an image: https://i.imgur.com/zUuh14P.png

Comment: I also cannot see the pointy part of the triangle at the top. It's an uneven line for some reason.

Comment: I made the viewport smaller so it was easier to see the top cut off and also the "wonkiness" https://i.imgur.com/eOmtTKR.png

Comment: If you take my example, and make it a little higher (.rectangle {height: **800px;**}
.triangle-up { border-bottom: **800px** solid black;} ), it looks perfect to me.  Please send your images with more contrast, it's nearly impossible to see any details because it's black on black...